# Karate start-up feature

Tags: karate

Need to execute a 'healthcheck' test(feature) before all the test-cases execute . 
This is like a preliminary test before executing the bunch of test-cases. Need a solutions to exit the platform if any of this pre check fails .

Answer (score 2):

Execute your health check feature from `karate-config.js` using `karate.call`/`karatecallSingle`,

if you feature fails to use java `System.exit` to force kill your test.

snippet for karate-config.js

```
try{
   var healthCheckInput = {};
   var healthcheckCall = karate.callSingle("healthCheck.feature",healthCheckInput );

   if (!<healcheckCondition>){
       java.lang.System.exit(0);
   }
 }
 catch(e){
   java.lang.System.exit(0);
 }
```

if your health check condition failed this would force exit your execution.

Not sure whether karate.abort() will give a soft exit from the platform, but if you are planning to implement try this as well.

> **Note:** since System.exit() force kills your execution you will not get any reports properly, but you can refer console logs/karate logs
>   for further investigation.

**EDIT:**

**Another Approach,**

You can use [karate Java API](https://github.com/intuit/karate#java-api) inside Junit `@BeforeClass` run your health status check feature.

```
@BeforeClass
    public static void startUpCheck() {
        Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap();
        args.put("inputOne", "valueOne");
        Map<String, Object> result = Runner.runFeature("classpath:stackoverflow/demo/healthCheck.feature", args, true);
       // also assert the 'result' if you want OR keep some assertions/match in your feature
    }
```

Comment: I tried  java.lang.System.exit(0); and it stopped the execution and never created a report . Is there any option to create a report in this scenario or it is a limitation ? .  karate.abort() from my understanding it skip execution of the next line of the script .

Comment: @Ramath as I mentioned in the note it will not generate a report. I am adding a new answer.