# Karate health-check at start-up from call single

Tags: javascript, karate

I am hoping for some help as I'm going a little crazy.
I want to perform a health check (see if the app is up by sending a GET request via call single in config.js
Im sending to localhost:8080/healthcheck.
If 200 then good -> start tests if not retry N times until the limit is reached => abort -> finish/fail without commencing test execution.

(namely [Karate start-up feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53939320/karate-start-up-feature/53939563#53939563))

I've seen a couple of links on stack overflow and while they mention implementing the same concept there is nothing that I was able to resolve my issue.

essentially if I start the app and run a simple request to http://localhost:8080/healthcheck
a 200 is returned with body {"status": "UP"}

However, as soon as I try to implement retry logic via js function -> it does not return a response from the get request supposedly sent.

Can someone please advise what I'm doing wrong -> point out how to resolve my feature?

The problem is in the function (as below) specifically response = karate.get(url);
Null is returned. But the app is up and responds successfully if hit directly.

Feature: Health Check Utility

Scenario: Run Health Check
* def baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/healthcheck'
* karate.log('Trying to reach:', baseUrl)
* def isServerUp =
"""
function(url, retries) {
while (retries-- > 0) {
var response = karate.get(url);
karate.log('Response:', response);
if (response && response.status === 200) {
var body = karate.toJson(response.response);
karate.log('Response Body:', body);
if (body.status === 'UP') {
return true;
}
}
karate.log('Waiting for server to start, retries left:', retries);
karate.log('Trying to reach: ', url);
java.lang.Thread.sleep(1000);
}
return false;
}
"""
* def retries = 120
* def result = isServerUp(baseUrl, retries)
* if (!result) karate.abort('Server did not start in time')

thanks heaps
jbart18

---

pretest health check code:
For anyone who stumbles upon this ticket -> here is the scripts to perform a pre-test health check (to localhost:8080)

---

Feature: Health Check

Scenario: Wait for Application to be Available

```
* def isUp = Java.type('utilities.HealthCheckUtils').waitForApplicationToBeAvailable('http://localhost:8080/healthcheck', 60)
* assert isUp == true
```

---

package utilities;

public class HealthCheckUtils {

```
public static boolean waitForApplicationToBeAvailable(String url, int timeoutInSeconds) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeoutInMillis = timeoutInSeconds * 1000;

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < timeoutInMillis) {
        try {
            int statusCode = org.apache.http.client.fluent.Request.Get(url)
                    .execute().returnResponse().getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // The application might not be up yet, so we catch the exception and retry
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000); // Wait for 1 second before retrying
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: see if this answer helps, let me know and I can close this as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59684516/143475

Comment: thanks so much, That was the thread I needed, @PeterThomas - it works a treat - please close as a duplicate.

For those who stumble upon this ticket - please see the description for the sample code im using to perform the pre-test health check